# Log table that grows like flash

Tags: mysql, maintenance, logs

I have my own app that get low traffic (like 100 ppl per day).

As part of my research I am 'logging' all the queries done to by the server in a table in the database. An example, if user enters home page it will register two queries for getting the data to display.

According to Google Analytics by average an user enters 7 pages per session, and in average I have 130 sessions per day. Assuming a bad design and think that in average a page does three queries would be a total 2730 queries per day.

Right now, my research does not have a deadline or finish point soon in the future and I am scare that at the end, all the data will be too much too process and study.

**Facts:**

- Right now in six months of working, SELECT COUNT(*), Throws 1.360.000
  rows and weights 5.56 GB.
- I am a master student of computer science with emphasis of user behavior.
- The server runs in a really low memory pc and there is not budget in the moment to changed it.
- I cannot change the code as it could change the results.
- I do not know anything about maintenance of a DB in a server and I just simply doing a service restart everyday.

**The questions:**

- Is it possible to overload the server of data considering the poor excuse of pc that I called server?
- Is it stupid to think to store the log in a way that every month will store it in a file and delete those rows from DB?
- Am I right to be worried about the size of the database?

Comment: Unless the design is much worse than you thought, there's a large discrepancy between the 1.4M rows and the expected 0.5M.  Could it be you're logging the fact that you're logging?

Comment: I haven't notice that in the few parts I have seen there is not logging of logging.

But as you said, yes it could be true, the design is really horrible but I cannot do anything about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now we don't know the specification of your "Server" so we can't tell if space might become an issue.

Apart from that, the answers you are searching for are just a case of interpolating the available data along a time line.

Answering your questions:

1. From a (MySQL) database perspective: It depends. If the InnoDB page size parameter is set to 4KB then the maximum tablespace size is 16TB. For 8KB page size the tablespace can grow to 32TB. For more information on the limitations of the tables / tablespace / OS limitations visit these links:

   - [15.8.1.7 Limits on InnoDB Tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-restrictions.html) (MySQL 8.0 documentation)
   - [C.10.3 Limits on Table Size](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/table-size-limit.html) (MySQL 8.0 documentation)
2. No. Other than observing the limitations of the MySQL specifications. Others before you have stored more data for less interesting cases.
3. No. See above.

So space might become an issue depending on your "server" hardware.

### Maintenance

As for maintaining your database, you might want to consider reading the following articles from the MySQL Documents site:

- [Chapter 7 Backup and Recovery](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/backup-and-recovery.html)

  - [7.3 Example Backup and Recovery Strategy](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/backup-strategy-example.html)
  - [7.4 Using mysqldump for Backups](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/using-mysqldump.html)
- [Chapter 8 Optimization](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/optimization.html)

  - [8.5 Optimizing for InnoDB Tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/optimizing-innodb.html)

I guess the **worst case** would be if you were to **lose all your data**. Consider performing a simple [mysqldump](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/using-mysqldump.html) to have a backup of your data. Then consider implementing a backup strategy.

Comment: I suppose available disk space on a low-spec server could be smaller than the InnoDB limits, so it would make sense to check that first.

Comment: Yes, I wrote that in my answer: _"So space might become an issue depending on your "server" hardware."_ (just above the title Maintenance).

Comment: Yes, it was just not obvious if you were talking about RAM or disk space.